# authentication not enabled+smtp+oracle UTL_SMTP

Tags: oracle11g, smtp

The smtp server return this error when i try to send email using UTL_SMTP.Please suggest the cause and solution to this error.the smtp server using zimbra community edition.

```
ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled
```

Comment: i think the cause is zimbra smtp auth problem

Answer (score 0):

ya dude even me too got this same error.Autually oracle is very highly securable  to access util_file and mail packages so u need to get appropriate privileges to access these packages.is you are DBA then you can use these packages very well.for detailed explanation just refer this  https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=690557.